# Submit Javascript Object with Array of Object inside to the API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, axios

Good day everyone,

I need a help on how to submit an object with array of object inside and the array of object should be from a checkboxes I've made.

This is my sample checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user.preferences" value="Hard" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user.preferences" value="Soft" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user.preferences" value="Small" />
```

My data javascript looks like this:

```
user:{ 
    preferences: [] 
}
```

When I alert the`user` using `JSON.stringify`, I can able to see a result something like this.

```
{"preferences": ["Soft","Small"]}
```

But the problem is, the api that I'm using needs a format like this:

```
{
    "preferences": [
     {
         "preference": "Hard"
     },
     {
         "preference": "Soft"
     },
     // so on and so forth
    ]
}
```

Please somebody help me. Thank you

Comment: are you processing this data or is it being sent directly by the form?

Comment: You should not have duplicate `id` attribute values in your HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `.map` each string in `preferences` to an object with that `preference` as its key/value:

```js
const user = {
  "preferences": ["Soft", "Small"]
};
user.preferences = user.preferences
  .map(preference => ({ preference }));
console.log(user);
```

Comment: But my another question is, how can I reverse it? from api to my javascript?

Comment: Just go the other way around: `.map({ preference }) => preference)`